# Products and Product namespace breaks my xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, namespaces

I'm trying to find some data in a xml sheet.

I could get the data from the xml if the namespaces where removed like this:

```
    $nodes = $data->xpath('//Products/Product/productId[.='.$sku.']/parent::*');
```

But when I load the real xml it is formatted as seen below with a namespace for the Products and a namespace for the Product

xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Products xmlns="http://config.services.bol.com/schemas/product-feed-1.1.xsd">
<Product xmlns="http://config.services.bol.com/schemas/product-1.1.xsd"><productId>9200000082000054</productId><ean>8719659945854</ean><title>SULADA Glossy TPU Bescherm Telefoon Hoesje Samsung Galaxy S8 - Rood</title><productUrlNL>https://www.bol.com/nl/p/sulada-glossy-tpu-bescherm-telefoon-hoesje-samsung-galaxy-s8-rood/9200000082000054/</productUrlNL><productUrlBE>https://www.bol.com/be/p/sulada-glossy-tpu-bescherm-telefoon-hoesje-samsung-galaxy-s8-rood/9200000082000054/</productUrlBE><imageUrl>https://s.s-bol.com/imgbase0/imagebase3/large/FC/4/5/0/0/9200000082000054.jpg</imageUrl><mpn>SS800003374</mpn><brand>GEEN</brand><familyName>SULADA Glossy TPU Bescherm Telefoon Hoesje Samsung Galaxy S8 - Rood</familyName><OfferNL><sellingPrice>14.95</sellingPrice><shippingCost>0.00</shippingCost><condition>new</condition><isDeliverable>true</isDeliverable><ultimateOrderTime>23:59:00.000+02:00</ultimateOrderTime><maximalDeliveryDay>12</maximalDeliveryDay><sellerType>P</sellerType></OfferNL><OfferBE><sellingPrice>14.95</sellingPrice><shippingCost>0.00</shippingCost><condition>new</condition><isDeliverable>true</isDeliverable><ultimateOrderTime>23:59:00.000+02:00</ultimateOrderTime><maximalDeliveryDay>12</maximalDeliveryDay><sellerType>P</sellerType></OfferBE><Gpc><segmentName>Communications</segmentName><familyName>Communications</familyName><className>Communicatieaccessoires</className><brickName>Hoesjes voor Mobiele Telefoon</brickName><chunkName>Hoesje voor mobiele telefoon</chunkName></Gpc><Category><unit>Electronics</unit><category>Mobile &amp; Tablets</category><productgroup>Phones Acc</productgroup><productsubgroup>Accessories Mobile</productsubgroup><subsubgroup>Accessories Mobile</subsubgroup></Category><description>&lt;lt/&gt;b&lt;gt/&gt;Let op! Dit hoesje past alleen op de Samsung Galaxy S8 (dus niet op de Samsung Galaxy S8+ en andere toestellen!&lt;lt/&gt;/b&lt;gt/&gt; Bescherm uw Samsung Galaxy S8 met dit geweldige telefoonhoesje. Dit hoesje is precies op maat gemaakt voor de Samsung Galaxy S8 waardoor het mooi aansluit. Het materiaal waaruit dit hoesje is vervaardigd is van zeer hoge kwaliteit. Met de aanschaf van dit duurzame telefoonhoesje zal uw smartphone gegarandeerd langer meegaan.</description><Properties><Property><key>AppearanceName</key><value>Physical</value></Property><Property><key>Colour</key><value>Meerkleurig</value></Property><Property><key>DeliveryMethod</key><value>Parcel</value></Property><Property><key>Material</key><value>Polycarbonaat</value></Property></Properties></Product>
<Product xmlns="http://config.services.bol.com/schemas/product-1.1.xsd"><productId>9200000074000054</productId><ean>7101125954841</ean><title>Adapter Samsung Galaxy J710 - J7 2016 Origineel</title><productUrlNL>https://www.bol.com/nl/p/adapter-samsung-galaxy-j710-j7-2016-origineel/9200000074000054/</productUrlNL><productUrlBE>https://www.bol.com/be/p/adapter-samsung-galaxy-j710-j7-2016-origineel/9200000074000054/</productUrlBE><imageUrl>https://s.s-bol.com/imgbase0/imagebase3/large/FC/4/5/0/0/9200000074000054.jpg</imageUrl><brand>Merkloos</brand><OfferNL><sellingPrice>12.95</sellingPrice><shippingCost>0.00</shippingCost><condition>new</condition><isDeliverable>true</isDeliverable><ultimateOrderTime>18:00:00.000+02:00</ultimateOrderTime><maximalDeliveryDay>1</maximalDeliveryDay><sellerType>P</sellerType></OfferNL><Gpc><segmentName>Electrical Supplies</segmentName><familyName>Electrical Connection/Distribution</familyName><className>Batterijen en opladers</className><brickName>Opladers</brickName><chunkName>Oplader voor mobiele telefoon</chunkName></Gpc><Category><unit>Electronics</unit><category>Mobile &amp; Tablets</category><productgroup>Phones Acc</productgroup><productsubgroup>Accessories Mobile</productsubgroup><subsubgroup>Accessories Mobile</subsubgroup></Category><description>Productomschrijving Adapter Samsung Galaxy J710 - J7 2016 Origineel  Heeft u behoefte aan een reserveoplader of kunt u uw huidige Samsung oplader niet meer vinden? Dan biedt deze 100% kwalitatieve Samsung oplader uitkomst! Haal ?m vandaag nog in huis!  De Samsung adapter bevat tal van voordelen. Zo is de adapter voorzien van een EU Plug en zorgen de minimale afmetingen ervoor dat deze Samsung adapter ideaal is om bij u te dragen. Schaf nu een originele Samsung adapter met de juiste datakabel aan en ben verzekerd van een optimale oplaadkwaliteit dankzij de capaciteit van 2 Ampère.  Kenmerken originele Samsung adapter  Deze adapter wordt geleverd zonder datakabel en heeft de volgende specificaties:Merk: Samsung Capaciteit: 2 Ampère Type: ETA-U90EWEG Contact: EU PlugAansluiting: USB 2.0</description><Properties><Property><key>AppearanceName</key><value>Physical</value></Property><Property><key>DeliveryMethod</key><value>Parcel</value></Property></Properties></Product></Products>
```

So now with the namespaces my xpath is not working anymore. I tried to register namespaces and change my xpath function to this (using some sample code i found):

php:

```
function findit($sku,$xml){
$xml->registerNamespace('prodfeed', 'http://config.services.bol.com/schemas/product-feed-1.1.xsd');
$xml->registerNamespace('prod', 'http://config.services.bol.com/schemas/product-1.1.xsd');

$nodes = $xml->xpath('/prodfeed:Products/prodfeed:Product/prod:productId[.='.$sku.']/parent::*');

var_dump($nodes);
```

}

But it's not working so far. Am i going in the right direction here?

But

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML document changes the default namespace when it gets to the Product element, so at this point you need to start using the prod namespace and not the prodfeed one.

You can also simplify the query, by moving the opening '[' back to before productId, which means you don't have to do the parent::* bit.

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('/prodfeed:Products/prod:Product[prod:productId=' . $sku . ']');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are registering 2 namespaces `prodfeed` and `prod`, but in your xpath you are using only 'prodfeed'.

Maybe it would help if you can change this line:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('/prodfeed:Products/prodfeed:Product/prod:productId[.='.$sku.']/parent::*');
```

to this:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('/prodfeed:Products/prod:Product/prod:productId[.=' . $sku . ']/parent::*');
```